# Way out of the war I offered to join?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

So, the Aztec invasion hit while I was dominating Europe as the restored Roman Empire. They were attacking Britain, which I held most of, and Scotland, which was an independent kingdom.

I had luckily declared war on a whole bunch of territories nearby and shipped my whole army out there to conquer, and was able to easily pick off the Aztec doom stacks until there were none left in my territory, and my warscore was 100%, so I quickly declared victory and went on conquering.

But Scotland, whose armies I had just destroyed, still had about 10K Aztecs running around. Stupidly, after I was done with everyone else, I offered to join this war. Now the score has been sitting at 100% for years, and it seems like there's something stopping her from enforcing her demands. Is there any way out of this?

My ruler died around then, but I can't remember if it was before or after I offered to join the war. Is there any chance the Queen of Scotland's death or mine should end the contract? Or will our heirs inherit the wars. I've also tried assassinating the Aztec guy, and the war just gets passed on.

Comment: If you aren't playing an Ironman game, you could switch to Scotland's ruler to see why he won't end the war.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely a bug in 2.2 - see the [notes](http://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/showthread.php?807667-Crusader-Kings-II-Open-Beta-Patch-2.2.0.1-Now-Available-checksum-QEVO) for the next patch.

> - Fixed bug where the AI did not end wars when at 100% warscore due to the recipient having previously declined a peace offer.

Certain wars are inherited, and it looks like this one is, so there's no fix other than wait for the patch or consoling over to the Aztecs and accepting peace if not ironman.